# Euclid's Algorithm for GCD Space Complexity

Tags: algorithm

This might seem a stupid question but is the space complexity for Euclid's GCD algorithm O(1) in the iterative implementation? I just wanted to confirm(couldn't find it on google)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you only need a temporary variable or two, not depending on the input, so it's O(1).

Comment: Thanks :) And if we do the recursive implementation, is the space complexity O(logn) where n is the bigger of the two numbers?

Comment: @s_123 It's O(log(smaller number)). This is all assuming arithmetic operations take constant time/space. This isn't necessarily true if we work with 1000 digit numbers.

Comment: Why do you say its O(log(smaller number))? As I see the algorithm, the bigger number is reduced by at least half in every two iterations. So I said its O(log(bigger number)). I cannot see why it can be O(log(smaller number)).

Comment: @s_123 because after the first iteration, the number that was previously smaller will become the bigger one. GCD(38, 1000000000) = GCD(38, 1000000000%38) = GCD(38, 18).

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks :)